# How can I display the student's name and his average grade on the console from a text file?

Tags: c#, file

I am new in C# coding, I am learning .NET FullStack, and I have a question about reading/writing with files. I have a txt file which consist of 3 lines and each line is in the following format:
First name,Last Name,Day of Birth,Month of borth,Year of Birth,Flag, grade 1,[more grades],Flag, distance in km from university to students department.

The data looks like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Yossi,Ben David,21,6,1990,FF,80,70,75,80,FF,100             |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Dany,Avigdor,18,4,1995,FF,70,65,50,FF,30                    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Yael,ShemTov,4,9,1997,FF,85,75,90,80,85,FF,100              |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to print the students name and average grade to the console, but I get an exception, I don't know why.

Thanks for answers.

Here is my code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
         try
            {
                string path = @"C:\Users\coral\Desktop\c#\.net course\StudentInfo.txt";
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {

                    using (StreamReader st = File.OpenText(path))
                    {
                        string k;
                        List<int> grade = new List<int>();
                        double avg;

                        while ((k = st.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            string[] words = k.Split(',');
                            foreach (var word in words)
                            {
                                while (word.StartsWith("FF") && word.EndsWith("FF"))
                                //if (word.StartsWith("FF") && word.EndsWith("FF"))
                                {
                                    grade.Add(int.Parse(word));
                                    //intList= int.Parse(num[word]);
                                }

                            }

                        }
                        int[] terms = grade.ToArray();
                        avg = terms.Average();
                        Console.WriteLine(avg);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error:" + e.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
}
```

The error message is:

```
Error:System.FormatException: System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) in System.Int32.Parse(String s) in FileExercise.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\coral\source\repos\FileExercise\FileExercise\Program.cs: 111 line
```

Comment: Could you please post some example data, along with the error message and stack trace.

Comment: The erroe message is:  Error:System.FormatException: 
     System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
     System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) in
     System.Int32.Parse(String s)
 in   FileExercise.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\coral\source\repos\FileExercise\FileExercise\Program.cs: 111 line

Comment: Some data:
Yossi,Ben David,21,6,1990,FF,80,70,75,80,FF,100
Dany,Avigdor,18,4,1995,FF,70,65,50,FF,30
Yael,ShemTov,4,9,1997,FF,85,75,90,80,85,FF,100

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
while (word.StartsWith("FF") && word.EndsWith("FF"))
                            {
                                grade.Add(int.Parse(word));
                            }
```

The first line ensures that `word` starts and ends with `FF`, but then you call `int.Parse`, which will throw an error if the text is not a number.

You could try something like:

```
int temp;
if (int.TryParse(word, out temp)) grade.Add(temp);
```

This will check if `word` can be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the grades are also split with a `,`.
So you have to parse only the grades after the first `FF` and before the second `FF`

```
//while ((k = st.ReadLine()) != null)
bool started = false;
foreach(var word in words){
    if(started && word == "FF")
    {
        break;
    }
    if(started)
    {
        grade.Add(int.Parse(word));
    }
    if(word == "FF")
    {
        started = true;
    }
}
```